# How to split the array of string in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to split the array of string in jquery.
for e.g.:

```
var input='a,b,c,d,e,f,g'
//i want to split in in array.
//check the condition that if  input of elements > 3. 
//then i need to remove the elements in array. then show the array like ex: output= 'a,b,c'
```

As I am new to `jQuery` please suggest me some jquery functions to implement this.

Comment: start by checking out split method of javascript not jquery: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp then maybe post some code with what you are stuck with

Comment: `'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'.split(',')`; see also [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Try Google first, without wanting to sound harsh, this really is javascript 101.

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'.split(',').slice(0, 3).join();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xaSn/

Answer (score 0):

```
var input='a,b,c,d,e,f,g';
var yourarray = input.split(",");
var newArray = new Array();
if(yourarray.length > 3){
    for(i = 0;i < 3;i++){
        newArray.push(yourarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. Splice and join

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RkXYq/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the jQuery library that is suitable for that, you need to use plain Javascript for that.

Use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string into an array, check the length, and use the [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) if you neet to get part of the array:

```
var arr = input.split(',');
if (arr.length > 3) {
  arr = arr.slice(0, 3);
}
```

Use the [`join` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) if you want the result as a comma separated string instead of an array:

```
var result = arr.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Ainput = input.split(",");
var output = input;
if(Ainput.length > 3)
{
    output = "";
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        output += Ainput[i]; 
    }
}
```

your input: a,b,c,d,e,f
your output: a,b,c

your input: a,b
your output: a,b